# Post Rest API call hangs waiting for status code response in Jenkins

Tags: java, rest

I have a POST API call which contacts a third party system. Sometimes when running on Jenkins, I believe it does not receive response (any status code) and the POST call hangs forever.

```
given()
    .header(<someheader>)
    .post(THIRD_PARTY_URL)
    .then().statusCode(HttpStatus.SC_OK)
    .extract().body().asString();
```

How to skip this status validation and include a timeout?

Answer (score 1):

To handle timeouts and skip status code validation in your REST Assured API call, you can use the `.timeout()` method along with the `.statusCode()` method.

```
given()
    .header(<someheader>)
    .post(THIRD_PARTY_URL)
    .then()
    .timeout(YOUR_TIMEOUT_IN_MILLISECONDS)
    .statusCode(HttpStatus.SC_OK)
    .extract().body().asString();
```

Keep in mind that using a timeout is a good practice to prevent your application from hanging indefinitely, especially in automated environments like Jenkins where such issues might be more prevalent.

If you want to skip the status code validation, you can remove the `.statusCode(HttpStatus.SC_OK)` part. This way, the request will not fail if the status code is not as expected, and it will only throw an exception if the request times out.

```
given()
    .header(<someheader>)
    .post(THIRD_PARTY_URL)
    .then()
    .timeout(YOUR_TIMEOUT_IN_MILLISECONDS)
    .extract().body().asString();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I'm not seeing timeout() in io.restassured.response. 
I tried something like
                    .then().time(Matchers.greaterThan(300L))
but this doesn't seem to assert when there is no response. Again infinite wait.